# How do I read accuracy and loss curves for a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, image-classification

I am using transfer learning and after evaluating the model I have the following plots which compare test and train accuracy and test and train loss:

[image]

what I see is that between test and train accuracy there is a large gap, but how do I interpret this result?

I don't think I am doing bad since I have a test accuracy of 0.880000.

I am trying to do image classification and in my training set I have 3200 images, while in the test set I have 800 images. As pretrained network I am using VGG16.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]Also the other metrics such as Recall,F1 score and Precision are good:

[image]

Comment: How balanced is your data? Accuracy is deceiving :) Plus your test loss is pretty high , see that you don't overfit.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a balanced dataset, so 800 images for each class.

Comment: @Aditya. Can I ask you what do you mean? So if I have a test loss which is high is sign that I am overfitting? Thanks again.

Comment: I meant that don't solely rely on accuracy ever.. Test Acc is naturally assumed to be lower than train except when you leak data between train and test etc. But what I meant is if your loss is .4-.5 range per epoch for test set, take a look at models preds and try to interpretate it using grad cam etc to verify its working and doing good!; Like a epoch loss of .7 is high, so dig into what happened there?